# Wifi problem with Elementary OS 6.1

Tags: wifi, networking

At manager wifi, when key disabled, not is possible enabled  again and scan for networks wifi.
The problem only solves using: "sudo nmcli radio wifi on" in shell terminal.
Is there any solution to the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the the NetworkManager